# Turn off paragraph indention for a single line

Tags: indentation

Is it possible to turn off the paragraph indention for a single line? I have the following use case: I open a new section which describes the task of an exercise. Since I use the font size `\large` for the section I don't want to use the section text for the task description.

Therefore I added the task description after the section. The disadvantage is that an indention is created when starting to write text after the task description.

What are possible solutions to this problem?

Comment: please comment to the answer, not you your question. Furthermore, it would be great if you would mark Jake's answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark left to his answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `\noindent` to turn off paragraph indentation for a single paragraph.